# the onKeydown event is being handled by android, thought the methods are there to handle the event

Tags: android, onkeydown

I have a menu activity which is getting extended from another activity.
I have my onKeyUp/Down methods written in the parent activity.

When the menu is shown on via a touch event then there is no focus shown anywhere, and that is when if I do an event from the external hardware(the intention is to control the device through an external hardware). the onKeyDown method is being handled by android and not by the activity. This only happens for the first time when the focus is shown nowhere(no menu item highlighted).but after i do a keyevent again from the hardware, it comes in the onKeyUp/Down events but not for the forst time.

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably returning super.onKeyDown/up on your overrides. Try returning true.

Comment: its actually not going into my code i.e before the event comes down to the onKeydown method written in my activity, it gets handled somewhere else